# git adding more files than wanted to commit

Tags: git

Why is git adding all files that are already in Index instead of only what is specified?

**Example adding with *--dry-run***:

```
$ git add -n file1
add 'file1'
add 'file2'

$ git --version
git version 2.1.3

$ uname -a
AIX myhost 1 7 ???????????? powerpc AIX
```

**Pictures showing more this behavior:**

[image]

**Adding *file1***:

[image]

**Reseting *file1***:

[image]

Comment: are those files linked in any way? output of `ls -li`?
if you add another file, the behavior remains the same?

Comment: No. They are not.

Comment: That's bizarre and wrong behavior. I'd suggest building a newer version of Git on your system, and if the new one continues to misbehave, debug from there.